# Why tabitem do not show view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, tabcontrol

I am workign on MVVM, and i have Main View in which i have a tabcontrol and 3 tabitems. Now on click to each tabitems i want to display a new view. (I have three Views).

My try to do that is :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:vm2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:vm3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm1:View1 x:Key="View1Display1"></vm1:View1>
        <vm2:View2 x:Key="ViewDisplay2"></vm2:View2>
        <vm3:View3 x:Key="ViewDisplay3"></vm3:View3>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TabControl Background="Green">
            <TabItem Height="20" Width="100" Header="Tab1" DataContext="{Binding Path=View1Display1}"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Height="20" Width="100" Header="Tab2" DataContext="{Binding Path=View1Display2}"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Height="20" Width="100" Header="Tab3" DataContext="{Binding Path=View1Display3}"></TabItem>
        </TabControl>          
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Where View1 is : (Similar is View2 and View3)

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.View1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">I am from View1</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs is :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new  ViewModel();
    }        
}
```

This is ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Why TabItem do not show the respective views on clicking to them even i have set datacontext corresponding to their View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding the `DataContext` on each `TabItem`, you need to bind the `Content`, and then you can bind each TabItem to an instance of its `ViewModel`, of Do that in the UserControls them selfs

```
 <TabControl Background="Green">
        <TabItem Height="20" Width="100" Header="Tab1" Content="{StaticResource View1Display1}"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Height="20" Width="100" Header="Tab2" Content="{StaticResource ViewDisplay2}"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Height="20" Width="100" Header="Tab3" Content="{StaticResource ViewDisplay3}"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

since your views are defined as static resource use `StaticResource` instead of binding

Comment: Do you also know to set it thorugh Datacontext ? (though i corrected my mistake)

Comment: To set the content using the DataContext you need to define DataTemplate for each TabItem, and use the DataType Property, (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx), there are plenty of articles and questions about that